# Windows partition no longer visible under Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. It was convenient to just click the Windows partition in the Ubuntu desktop launcher. This function gradually disappeared and now nothing happens when I click it. My Windows is shut down, not hibernated.

I could maybe start making experiments with fstab. But I think the result is better if someone here guides me how to get back this nice function, just to click the icon in the launcher.

(This question is not about GRUB and boot-loaders. They work fine and both Ubuntu and Windows start as I choose. This is about the Ubuntu desktop, where I can no longer reach the Windows partition with one click from the Ubuntu launcher.)

Sorry for many edits, I have been struggling with wrapping code tags around the listings.

parted

```
ycc@x360:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPCX-6 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB  273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB  16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   315GB  315GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      315GB   319GB  4194MB  linux-swap(v1)  Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      319GB   382GB  62.9GB  ext4            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      382GB   483GB  101GB   ext4            Basic data partition          msftdata
 7      483GB   484GB  1028MB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 8      484GB   500GB  16.1GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, msftdata
```

gparted

[image: gparted].

fstab

```
ycc@x360:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c9b9e601-f78a-41d8-a4f4-87e276b4aeb7 /               ext4                        errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9ADF-D1D2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=782e4b9f-4941-48bc-a1bf-5883e28cb174 /home           ext4            defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=c35d5bd1-960c-4e1a-8f6e-d73af393bfc3 none            swap    sw                  0       0
```

mount

```
ycc@x360:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1916132k,nr_inodes=479033,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=387088k,mode=755)
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=387088k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
ycc@x360:
```

Comment: hello is this a grub matter, do you mean your Windows partition is not visible in grub - boot - manager ? Have seen your thread a bit too late and it seems to be duplicate of this contribution here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/795266/grub-doesnt-recognize-windows-8 Please inform me, if this is a matter of grub or not.

Comment: Hi. This is not a GRUB-question. I can boot and run both Ubuntu and Windows. The question you mention is not a duplicate. I think I know the answer to the question you quote, so I posted an answer to it, / The problem in my question here occurs when Ubuntu is running. In the Ubuntu desktop I can no longer open the Windows partition from the Ubuntu desktop launcher. (Thanks for pointing out, I clarified my question.)

Comment: `fdisk` does not work well with GPT, didn't it tell you? Substitute its output with `sudo parted -l` please. And tell us in which device (`/dev/sd??`) is the Windows partition that you are trying to access. Also, a screenshot of Gparted can be helpful.

Comment: fdisk didn't tell me that, but I might have figured it out from the listing :). I honestly learn something here every time I ask. / Windows ought to be in sda3, isn't that the only possibility? / I think sda7 is HP recovery and sda8 is Windows recovery partitions. I think sda7, 8 fill no function now that the disk is repartitioned? I tried to remove them in Win 10, but was not allowed. Can it be risky to remove them with Gparted? Long time ago I remember manipulating system partition from Gparted on live media. Minor problems with flags occurred as I remember.

Comment: After having been invisible for a couple of days (the main question here), the Windows partition can again be accessed today from Ubuntu. Maybe difficult to find such an inconstant problem. It comes and goes. I can't say what I do differently.