# Grub doesn't recognize Windows 8

Tags: grub2, 16.04, windows, 64-bit

I have set up Ubuntu using [this guide](http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/). Everything worked completely fine, but Grub wouldn't show Windows 8 in it's menu.
So I googled a solution, and found+used boot-repair.
Even after the fix, Windows 8 wouldn't show up.
I am 100% sure that Windows is still installed on a partition.
(Please excuse any errors you may find, as I am not a native english speaker.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is only a spell-checking matter of Ubuntu or something has been overseen here :

So I assume that grub2 is installed already but Ubuntu is performing in the wrong way the command update-grub instead of update-grub2 ?!

Try to run in terminal simply this command when you have entered your password after this, it should work and then you can re-boot your machine and Windows 8 should be visible in the boot-manager of grub2.

> sudo update-grub2 (and not: sudo update-grub)

Inform me, if this worked.

Comment: Nope,sorry. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repair GRUB2. Your GRUB2 is fine, but it must be activated in UEFI.
(Now that UEFI has replaced BIOS, GRUB2 can no longer install itself automatically. It must be activated. That is one part of what Microsoft calls "Secure Boot".)

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot with Windows 10. After the Ubuntu install, Windows was still the only operating system seen at boot. To fix that I did the following:

To activate the Ubuntu bootloader (GRUB2) you must open the computer's UEFI (which has replaced BIOS) and look for the setting of bootloader. There is a choice between Windows and Ubuntu bootloader. When you change this setting from Windows to Ubuntu bootloader, all will work well: When you now turn on the computer, GRUB2 starts and you can choose to boot either Ubuntu or Windows.

It is a little "tricky" to enter UEFI in Windows 10 (or Windows 8). (You can not just turn on the power switch and hack on the escape/f2 key or similar, any more, like you did to enter the "old" BIOS.)

To enter UEFI, you must first start Windows. You then press restart of Windows and hold down the shift key at the same time. When the computer then restarts (with shift having been pressed down as you issued the command) you get several choices how to enter UEFI settings and choose bootloader (You should choose "troubleshooting"!).

Another way to make the computer do this kind of "deep" restart (and open UEFI) can be found under Windows settings (see below).

This (shift/restart) is also the way to make the computer boot from external media, like USB. (But then you don't choose "troubleshooting" when the computer restarts, then you choose the USB-boot option, of course.)

So I think you got Ubuntu and GRUB2 in place. You must just activate Ubuntu bootloader (instead of Windows) in UEFI (BIOS).

I have not tried this in Win 8. But from what I Google you can open the UEFI in a similar way in Windows 8 as I just described for Windows 10.

Edit:

[Here](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-password/four-methods-to-access-uefi-bios-setup.html#method2) is how to enter UEFI in Windows 8 and 10, if you go via PC settings (and not just press shift/restart):

Windows 8/8.1: Settings > Change PC Settings > General > Advanced startup > Restart Now > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings > Restart

Windows 10: Start > Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Advanced startup > Restart now > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings > Restart

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer,but Ubuntu is the only OS being shown to me in GRUB. Can I access the (U)EFI somehow in Ubuntu?

Comment: So you could make the computer boot into GRUB by changing UEFI?

Comment: I now see that I have misunderstood your question. Sorry. I hope someone who knows GRUB2 better than I do, can come in and help you.